# Site displaying 'Not Secure' after installing SSL cert

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, https

After installing my SSL cert retrieved from GoDaddy.com, my site displays the 'Not Secure' warning message near the URL (also the red line over the HTTPS). I contacted GoDaddy support and they said the cert is valid and working and there must be something wrong with the SSL installation. I followed this [guide](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl) for installing the SSL. When I look at the cert (Chrome -> Inspect -> Security) it shows the SSL cert with all the correct information but says 'This certificate was signed by an unknown authority.' I used the SSL cert (root.crt) provided by my CA (GoDaddy.com), however I believe it says its a self signed cert (even though I used the cert from GoDaddy). I have never set up a SSL before so I am unsure of the correct process or what needs to be done, any help/advice to figuring out what is wrong is greatly appreciated. (For the sake of security I won't provide any keys or certs, if there is anything not security wise that I can provide to help, please let me know). Also I am using Tomcat 8 to handle the web server.

Comment: This is *likely* a case of a missing intermediate certificate. Can you scan your site with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and see if it says something along those lines? If it is a missing intermediate, you'll need to consult your web server's documentation about supplying a full certificate chain.

Comment: It won't be able to reach it as its not live yet, I have a intermediate certificate but everytime I try to install it, it gives me the message 'certificate already exists under <root> alias' and asks if I want to add it anyways (which I hit 'no' so as to not break anything

Comment: Ok It just let me install the intermediate and still gives me the same thing, 'Not Secure'

Comment: Also the message I get on the Chrome security tab says 'Subject Alternative Name Missing: The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain name or IP address' and 'Certificate Error: There are issues with this sites certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).' if that helps at all.

Comment: Also under that it says 'Secure Connection' and 'Secure Resources'. Also, oddly enough it says the CA is Avast (Untrusted CA) but on the server it says the CA is our site name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix this error, it turns out that the CSR that is submitted to the CA (aka GoDaddy) MUST be made on the server in which it will be used otherwise the cert will be invalid or not work on that device. You can refer here for information on that: [https://www.sslshopper.com](https://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-a-csr-certificate-signing-request.html)